# View data on PostgreSQL database in Ubuntu

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

I am running a Django based website on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet, using PostgreSQL. The site is running and data is being stored in the database successfully.

How do I view the data in the database? I was able to do this easily using PGadmin on my windows machine before I pushed it to production. How do I do this now that there is no GUI?
Can I still use PGadmin somehow and "remote" into my droplet?

Thanks!

Comment: you can install pgadmin and use it like before. you can follow https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-pgadmin4-server-mode

Comment: Why not just the Django admin?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is there a way to see the id of the field in Django admin?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe this is incorrect practice, but I have a few users (which I can see on Django admin), and I need their "id". The automatically generated number when the user is created and stored in the database. This is visible when looking at the table data, but doesn't seem to be available on Django Admin